# Passing the complete Object Instance, NOT just the object id, from a Django template to view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to pass full object instances from my django template to my view as the values associated with checkbox inputs. When I try to do so, I only get the object's unicode method representation and am thus unable to access any of the object's particular fields in my view.

Is there either a way to pass the actual object from the template to the view or, instead, a way to use that unicode representation in the view to access the actual object and its corresponding fields?
I don't want to use 'publication.id' as my checkbox value because I can't guarantee the ids will never change.

Current code:

```
mytemplate.html
    <form method="get" action="processData">
        {% for publication in mydata %}
            <input type="checkbox" name="item-selection" value="{{publication}}">
        {% endfor % }

view.py
    items = request.GET.getlist('item-selection')
    for x in items:
        print x         # this prints the unicode mehtod's return value
        x.datafield1    # I want to access each object's data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this can't possibly work: sending data from the browser to the view is done via HTTP post, and you can only post data, you can't post objects.

But you've said the solution yourself: use the IDs. Who cares if the IDs change? All that matters is that you get the ID as it currently is.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item-selection" value="{{publication.id}}"><label>{{ publication.name }}</label>
```

...

```
item_ids = request.GET.getlist('item-selection')
items = Item.objects.filter(id__in=item_ids)
```

Comment: aaah ok, thank you! I wasn't sure if perhaps objects themselves could somehow be passed as data and then that data "recreated" back into the object in the view. (sorry for my naivety- I've been reading the docs but miss the big picture sometimes) Anyways, I really appreciate your help! @DanielRoseman